# Custom Listview in android?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have some problem about customlistview.How can i do this screen? First seem like all of them button but all line must be listview.Some item is nested.I am a bit confused. Can anybody help me?

[image]

Comment: whats your problem what you had tried?

Comment: How can i do the column.They are not button.If ı do listview can be clickable background.If i dont do button how can i press like a list.

Comment: you need to create/desig an layout for single row first. then you can inflate it in your listview using adapters.

Comment: http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429&q=customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that every item on the screen will be inside one ListView.
You can then create custom Adapter for every item using your own layout xml. Just think of it as you are making just one layout(or what you called button).
Adapter will then use that layout and populate it for every item in the object list automatically.

For click behavior, you can create custom Drawable with proper state etc. This will make user feel like they are clicking on a button.

What you are trying to do is definitely not a button, so dont think you are making button here.